# css hide text node but show its children

Tags: css, sass

I have html and css selectors as below. I'd like to hide the text node but leave its children. ie. the text node "Dashboard"

```
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <span class="icon">
          <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
        </span>
        Dashboard  
    </a>
</li>
```

css

```
li > a > :not(span){
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: You can't do this using CSS because CSS is applied to elements. You can't apply it to a text-node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a CSS-only example using `text-indent` to hide the text but keep elements inside visible. This doesn't require you to modify your HTML at all.

```css
/* icon styles just for example: */

.icon {
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* hiding happens here: */

a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}

a > * {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-indent: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></span>
      Dashboard
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS selectors can only select elements (or pseudo-elements), not contiguous text.

But if you want something like `display: none`, you can use `font-size: 0`, and restore the desired value on the children elements.

```css
@import 'http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';
li > a {
  font-size: 0;
}
li > a > * {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <a href="#">
    <span class="icon">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </span>
    Dashboard  
  </a>
</li>
```

There is also `visibility: hidden`, which will hide the text but following contents won't move to take the freed space.

```css
@import 'http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';
li > a {
  visibility: hidden;
}
li > a > * {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <a href="#">
    <span class="icon">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </span>
    Dashboard  
  </a>
  Following text
</li>
```

Comment: AFAIK the use of the universal selector that way can be expensive in terms of performance or is it no longer an issue?

Comment: @Aziz I'm sure browsers can handle it without problems. But if it's known that there can only be `span` children, `li > a > span` may be faster, yes.

Answer (score 0):

CSS cannot access stray text nodes, the ideal solution would be wrapping the text inside a `<span>` with specific class for hiding, for example:

```
<span class="link-text">Dashboard</span>
```

then hiding with CSS:

```
li > a > .link-text {
  display: none;
}
```

However, if you cannot modify the HTML, you can try another technique which "clips" the text with `overflow: hidden` while adding fixed height/width to your container/link:

```
li > a {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}
```