# Create a css rule for all elements except one class?

Tags: html, css

I have a html like this:

```
<div class="portfolio-descr">
    <span class="posted-in"></span>                             
    <h3><a href="">Name</a></h3>           
    Some text <!-- HIDE THIS -->
</div>
```

I want to hide `Some text` but not the `<h3>` tag, purely with CSS like this:

```
.portfolio-descr:not(h3) {
  display:none;
}
```

But all the elements are hidden.

Comment: can't you wrap `Some text` in some tag? P.S you probably meant to write `.portfolio-descr *:not(h3) { ... }`

Comment: No, I can not. That why I have to use except in css

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css hide text node but show its children](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41204913/css-hide-text-node-but-show-its-children)

Comment: If you cannot change the HTML, please add that fact to your question.

Comment: The question which was suggested as a dup target has a number of good solutions, including using margins and/or a font size of zero.

Comment: @tuanptit you need to correct html.Please check updated ans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use display property it will affect both parent and its children, but you can use visibility property to achieve your goal. (I added some text to .posted-in span to show the result better)

```css
.portfolio-descr{
  visibility:hidden;
}

.portfolio-descr>*{
  visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-descr">
        <span class="posted-in">abc</span>                             
        <h3><a href="">Name</a></h3>           
        Some text
</div>
```

Comment: But I believe this will leave empty space where the "Some text" was, and that may not be what the OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

put space between parent class and descendant `h3`
otherwise `h3` considered as part of parent class `portfolio-descr`

```
.portfolio-descr > :not(h3) {
    display:none;
}
```

Correct HTML :

Put `some text` inside inline/block html element as per need

```
<div class="portfolio-descr">
    <span class="posted-in"></span>
    <h3><a href="">Name</a></h3> <span>Some text</span>
  </div>
```

Working  [`plunker`](https://plnkr.co/edit/HbsmQjInmdB7alptFQkr?p=preview)

Comment: Please check plunker.Its working .Please inspect html wheather there any other css overwriting

Comment: I do not believe this will hide "Some text" as the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide just the text but not h3 and span tags,one of the options is to make the font-color and background to be the same

check this snippet

```css
.portfolio-descr:not(h3):not(span) {
  color: white;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-descr">
  <span class="posted-in"></span> 
  <h3><a href="">Name</a></h3> Some text
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I don't think this does what you think it does. The `.portfolio-descr:not(h3):not(span)` selects an element which both has the `.portfolio-descr` class, **and** is itself neither an `h3` nor a `span`. Your code only works because the `h3` does not inherit background color.